# Move large static array into a separate file: .c or .h?

Tags: c

I've got a large pre-calculated 4D array written in C:

```
static float coeffs[257][4][8][2] = 
{ 
 { 
  { { +0.999778485478688f, +0.021047089441095f }, { +1.000000000000000f, -0.000000000000000f }, { +0.999778485478688f, -0.021047089441095f }, { +0.999556987314086f, -0.029762881439599f }, { +0.999778485478688f, -0.021047089441095f }, { +1.000000000000000f, +0.000000000000000f }, { +0.999778485478688f, +0.021047089441095f }, { +0.999556987314086f, +0.029762881439599f },  },
  { { +0.999778485478688f, +0.021047089441095f }, { +0.999556987314086f, +0.029762881439599f }, { +0.999778485478688f, +0.021047089441095f }, { +1.000000000000000f, +0.000000000000000f }, { +0.999778485478688f, -0.021047089441095f }, { +0.999556987314086f, -0.029762881439599f }, { +0.999778485478688f, -0.021047089441095f }, { +1.000000000000000f, -0.000000000000000f },  },
  { { +0.999778485478688f, -0.021047089441095f }, { +1.000000000000000f, +0.000000000000000f }, { +0.999778485478688f, +0.021047089441095f }, { +0.999556987314086f, +0.029762881439599f }, { +0.999778485478688f, +0.021047089441095f }, { +1.000000000000000f, +0.000000000000000f }, { +0.999778485478688f, -0.021047089441095f }, { +0.999556987314086f, -0.029762881439599f },  },
  { { +0.999778485478688f, -0.021047089441095f }, { +0.999556987314086f, -0.029762881439599f }, { +0.999778485478688f, -0.021047089441095f }, { +1.000000000000000f, +0.000000000000000f }, { +0.999778485478688f, +0.021047089441095f }, { +0.999556987314086f, +0.029762881439599f }, { +0.999778485478688f, +0.021047089441095f }, { +1.000000000000000f, +0.000000000000000f },  },
  }, 

 .
 .
 .
 },
}
```

It's about 1500 lines, so I would like to move it into a separate file.

The array should be static as it is used only in a single C file.

The question is, should such static arrays be moved into a header file and then included as `#include "coeffs.h"`, or should they be a separate C file included as `#include "coeffs.c"`? Does it matter?

Comment: If you are going to `#include` it, it should be a `.h` file. Personally, I would put it in a `.c` file, compile and link it, and put an `extern` declaration in a `.h` file.

Comment: If it's going to be used by a single other file, you can use `#include`. However, this has some disadvantages -- e.g. if the table is large the recompilation time will increase if you edit the file that include it. However, if you place it in a separate file, it can't be `static`.

Comment: When you place `static` data into header files, there is a possibility that it will be included more than once, and then each including translation unit will have it's own copy of it. Which will lead to increased binary size and possible logical bugs. So I suggest to define it in the TU which is actually using it. If you don't want to clutter it, define it in a separate `C` file and add a corresponding `H` file with and define some extra interface for accessing it as desired.

Comment: But if you don't want the extra overhead, you can solve your dilemma by placing it into neither `c` or `h`, but into, say, `inc` file so it stands out.

Comment: As far as the C compiler is concerned the choice of name (and extension) doesn't matter much for the `#include "filename"`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yet it is a bit dangerous to place it in `C` file as the compiler without a correct Makefile will try to compile and link it separately. And, of course, it will confuse whoever is working with this code

Comment: @EugeneSh. I like the ".inc" idea. Maybe add that as the answer?

Comment: I would consider not storing it in a source at all, and instead read the data from a file during runtime.

Comment: An editor or IDE may choose some indentation and highlighting rules based on the extension, so something standard like .c or .h would be better if that is a concern. (I guess you won't be editing it much though.) How about `"coeffs.c.h"` or `"coeffs.c_data.h"`?

Comment: Is compiling the data into the code really the best option, as opposed to reading it from separate data file at run time? If the data needs to updated, the entire program would need to be recompiled. Holding large datasets in a separate data file is honestly the more typical solution, even at the cost of added initialization overhead.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA Dimensions and data will hardly change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static arrays contain definitions, so they need to be in a `.c` file.

If you put them in `.h` files, different translation units will define the same constants.

In your case, `data` is *static*, so by no means it will be in a `.h` file.  It is not linked with anything externally, so no need to declare it in a header file.

If the static data is generated by some other program in a file "data", you can do so:

file.c:

```
static float coeffs[257][4][8][2] = 
{
#include "data"
}
```

and generate "data" as a valid C-input.

Comment: Indeed, the data are generated (written to file) using MATLAB.

Comment: @Danijel Other option is to generate a full `.c` file with the definition of coeffs, instead of generating only the data as a set of literal constants, and you declare `external float coeffs[...]` in some header file.  If you do so, you must not declare `coeffs` as *static*, but with *external* linkage.

Comment: Alternatively make a proper .h file `coeffs.h` with header guards and everything, then place a single macro inside it: `#define COEFFS_INIT { /* all data */ }`. Then from the .c file do `static float coeffs[257][4][8][2] = { COEFFS_INIT };`

Comment: @Lundin This is well if the data in imported a single time, otherwise you duplicate memory.

Comment: What do you mean? Only the variable in the .c file takes up memory. The header file only contains an initializer list.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, it makes sense to put it in a header file if it is needed in many translation units.  If you statically import from many translation units, it will be imported in each one the same data.  Hence, duplication of memory...

Comment: There's literally no difference between my header file proposal and your raw file include other than the header file can have header guards to _prevent_ multiple definitions, as well as having a named constant instead of a cryptic `#include` in the middle of the initializer list.

Comment: @Lundin Ususally, all the generated data files keep a comment on the first line, like `/*This file was generated by ...*/`.  It's not cryptic.  But yes, your solution is the same as I said.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a `.h` file nor a `.c` file.

The `.h` extension indicates that the file is intended for possible inclusion in several translation units. This is not the case.

The `.c` extension indicates that the file is the main file of a translation unit. Some IDEs will automatically build it separately if found within the project folder.

Hence, (almost) any extension which is not `.h` or `.c` would be better, e.g. `.inc`. The `.c` file needing `coeffs` would then include it as follows:

```
#include "coeffs.inc"
```

I would recommend putting the entire definition of `coeffs` in the file because the initializer list and the dimensions of the `coeffs` array are tightly coupled.

If `coeffs` is needed in several translation units, then of course it should be declared as `extern` in a `.h` file and the definition/initialization could then be in a separate `.c` file. However, in this case where `coeffs` is `static` (private within a single translation unit), the above approach is better so that it is clear that the array is local to the translation unit.